# Conky-Manager install issues

Tags: 12.04, conky

I have been trying to install conky manager. At first, the errors were

```
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 conky-manager : Depends: libgee-0.8-2 (>= 0.8.3) but it is not installable
```

Now, the commands I have tried are

```
sudo apt-get install conky-manager
sudo apt-get -qq -f -m build-dep conky-manager
sudo apt-get purge
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

I have even gone so far as to download the .deb file from the conky-manager website. And git clone libgee.

The NEW error that im getting is:

```
E: Build-Depends dependency for conky-manager cannot be satisfied because the package valac-0.26 cannot be found
```

And:

```
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have googled, skimmed forums, and done everything that I can think of aside from a fresh install. Just curious if anyone else has had this issue before, and if there is any advice offered. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a quick search for the valac-0.26 deb file.  Here is a download link.

```
http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/amd64/valac-0.26/download
```

If there are any other problems, feel free to let us know what error messages you are seeing.  Happy Conkying!

Comment: so sorry for the late reply. I will give that a shot. Thank you!!!

Comment: No worries!  Hopefully that helps you out.  :)

Comment: Late response, however, wrong architecture. I have installed the correct files, will test to see if it works after restart.

Comment: Fair enough.  At least my answer lead to your solution. :)

Comment: thank you for the nudge in the right direction :) tis working now :D